# Simple function in js for sliding navbar don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i got this function, it should change the background color of navbar and make it fixed while i scroll down the site but it doesn't work. Please tell me, is there problem with the function or I'm making mistake somewhere else ? Also tried to add function in html file but it still doesn't work and tried function from w3school to make it work.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('siteNav.scroll');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('siteNav.scroll');
  }
})
```

```css
#siteNav {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.siteNav.scroll {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
}

#siteNav .logo {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
}

#siteNav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#siteNav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #383838;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#siteNav ul li a {
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #000000;
}

#siteNav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

#siteNav.scroll ul li a {
  color: #000000;
}

#siteNav ul li a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
  <nav id="siteNav">
    <img class="logo" src="images/img2-logo.png" alt="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#mission">MISSION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--header-->

  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>aaaaaaa <br><a>aaaaaa-aaaaaa</a></br>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Issue

The CSS selector `.siteNav.scroll` searches for an element with the classes `siteNav` and `scroll`, like so:

```
<nav class="siteNav scroll">
```

However, your `.addClass("siteNav.scroll")` is actually adding *one single class* called `siteNav.scroll`, like so:

```
<nav class="siteNav.scroll">
```

#### The Solution

```
.addClass("siteNav scroll")
```

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('siteNav scroll');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('siteNav scroll');
  }
})
```

```css
body { height: 5000px; }

#siteNav {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.siteNav.scroll {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
}

#siteNav .logo {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
}

#siteNav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#siteNav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #383838;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#siteNav ul li a {
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #000000;
}

#siteNav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

#siteNav.scroll ul li a {
  color: #000000;
}

#siteNav ul li a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
  <nav id="siteNav">
    <img class="logo" src="images/img2-logo.png" alt="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#mission">MISSION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--header-->

  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>aaaaaaa <br><a>aaaaaa-aaaaaa</a></br>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

#### A "Better" Solution

I don't see that you'd need the `siteNav` class (as Andy G points out) unless you'll be using multiple element types (other than `<nav>`) for this.

Instead, simplify it to `.addClass("scroll")` / `.removeClass("scroll")` and change your CSS selector to `nav.scroll { ... }` (or `#siteNav.scroll { ... }`).

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('scroll');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('scroll');
  }
})
```

```css
body { height: 5000px; }

#siteNav {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav.scroll {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
}

#siteNav .logo {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
}

#siteNav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#siteNav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #383838;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#siteNav ul li a {
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #000000;
}

#siteNav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

#siteNav.scroll ul li a {
  color: #000000;
}

#siteNav ul li a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
  <nav id="siteNav">
    <img class="logo" src="images/img2-logo.png" alt="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#mission">MISSION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--header-->

  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>aaaaaaa <br><a>aaaaaa-aaaaaa</a></br>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: If there is only one `nav` element per page then an alternative would be to target this via `nav.scroll` and remove the dependence on `siteNav` (id or class).

Comment: Cool. Yes, the class siteNav seemed redundant, although the id could still be appropriate for JS targetting.